# How to store a Query Snapshot forEach return in a map (Flutter Firebase)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, foreach

I have this code:

```dart
databaseReference
          .collection("myCol").doc('myDoc')
          .get()
          .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((f) => myMap == f.data);
      })
```

And it returns: `{name: Holly, city: NYC, index: 30}`

I want to store in this format: **ExpectedResult**

```dart
[30, [{'name': holly, 'city': NYC}, {ANOTHER EXAMPLE}]]
```

This is what I tried:

```dart
snapshot.docs.forEach((f) => myMap[f.data()["index"]].add(f.data()));
```

But it throws this error:

> Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null.

How can I reach my expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do this:

```dart
var MyMap;
snapshot.docs.forEach((f) => _allEvents = f.data());
```

Now you will have the content of the snapshot inside 'MyMap' variable and can do all the transformations through it.